# Python Django: How to force a Floatfield Output to have scientific Notation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want a Django Floatfield to show 10e7 instead of 10000000 in the browser.

If i did for example

`self.fields['energy']=forms.Floatfield( initial= '%.4g' %10000000 )`

then I'm trying to set a string value, but 'initial' only accept float.
So this way don't work and I don't know another way.

What can I do instead?

Comment: Have you tried `DeimalField`? `Decimal` data type in programming languages should be used for human friendly output: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield

Comment: I haven't tried it but here's python decimal doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: @ShangWang I changed Floatfield to DecimalField, but it still shows '1000000', I also tried it with `initial=Decimal(1e7)`, but the `initial` from DecimalField also accept float-only inputs

Comment: Can you do the formatting in the template?

Comment: How? You mean like `{{forms.energy | scienceformat}}`

Comment: I think, this is possible, if anything like 'scienceformat' exists, but I never heard of it